# error compiling lua bridge

Tags: visual-c++, lua, luabridge

i was trying the compile lua bridge from the repository
https://github.com/vinniefalco/LuaBridge/releases

However was getting the error 
C2953   'luabridge::FuncTraits': class template has already been defined  LuaBridgeDemo   luabridgedemo-1.0\luabridgedemo-1.0\luabridge\luabridge.h   1436

Upon closer examination there are two similar structures declared on the header file

```html
template <typename R, typename D>
struct FuncTraits <R (*) () THROWSPEC, D>
{
  static bool const isMemberFunction = false;
  typedef D DeclType;
  typedef R ReturnType;
  typedef None Params;
  static R call (DeclType fp, TypeListValues <Params> const&)
  {
    return fp ();
  }
};


template <class T, typename R, typename D>
struct FuncTraits <R (T::*) () const THROWSPEC, D>
{
  static bool const isMemberFunction = true;
  static bool const isConstMemberFunction = true;
  typedef D DeclType;
  typedef T ClassType;
  typedef R ReturnType;
  typedef None Params;
  static R call (T const* const obj, DeclType fp, TypeListValues <Params> const&)
  {
    (void)tvl;
    return (obj->*fp)();
  }
};
```

I am using Visual C++ 2015. Is there any setting or code change that I need to do to resolve this error.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just removed the duplicate method signatures, it compiled after that.